# how to get IP ID, SEQ id, ACK id in python tcp socket?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

Python socket in linux (bsd socket)

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('www.google.com', 80))
s.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
s.recv(1024)
```

Is it possible to get IP ID, SEQ id, ACK id for the curren `s` object?

- best if not tampering too much with normal tcp socket internals.
- best if the tracking could work in real-time.
- replacing normal AF_INE/SOCK_STREAM with raw packets is inefficient because you have to re-implement the whole TCP stack in user space.
- The purpose of the question is that I am adding diagnosis code, would be attached to an existing project, they use normal TCP socket extensively.
- I tried to use `AF_PACKET` to capture raw incoming & outgoing packets, but feels a really ugly hack.
- Besides, if multi-threaded sockets are sending the **same** request concurrently in TCP, you can't tell which captured packet belongs to which, because the tuple (srcip, srcport, dstip, dstport, proto_num) are all the same.

An althernative way to asking the question is how to label the packet stream tuple (srcip, srcport, dstip, dstport, proto_num) to inode/fd on Linux?

Is this possible at all? Maybe using `netlink`? I am sure there's a seq/ack id to inode table somewhere at kernel which could be exposed.

Under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + python 2.7 with root of course.

Comment: I believe you could access this infomration using the dpkg library found here: https://code.google.com/p/dpkt/ I haven't looked into this too deeply though :)

Comment: @JamesMills That requires you to construct raw packets, which is incompatible with existing code which use the normal socket extensively.

Comment: (I've not tried) -- But can't you get the raw socket data from normal python socks and parse them with dpkt? I remember another useful library in this category but for the life of me I can't remember what is called!

Comment: I found it! http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/ -- I recall this is used extensively in some firewall/monitoring appliacnes by an Australian vendor. You might have better luck with this library ;)

Comment: @JamesMills Scapy is good at crafting packets, not extracting info from existing ones. Given raw packet streams e.g. concurrent 100x requests to ("google.com", 80), you can't tell which is which because (srcaddr, srcport, dstaddr, dstport, proto_num) are all the same.

Comment: @JamesMills The point is, can you label the tuple (srcaddr, srcport, dstaddr, dstport, proto_num) from packet stream to fd/inode?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39224/discussion-between-james-mills-and-est)

Comment: @JamesMills label the stream based on fd, how? Please do share the trick :D

Comment: You can use the identity of the socket object in the stream. i.e: `id(sock)`

Comment: @JamesMills Huh? id() is memory address, fd is file handler, when you observe tcp streams using dpkt/scapy/libpcap the only thing you can get is the addr:port pair tuple. What do you mean by `id(sock)` ?

Comment: Isn't the `(addr, port)` tuple enough?

Comment: @JamesMills I have the code in the question, Given the tuple as 5 variables can you show me how?

Comment: **Why** do you want this information?

Comment: @BrianWhite so I don't need to tcpdump alongside my program everytime.

Comment: So it's for debugging only?  You don't need the information for operation of your program?  If so...  It's not worth the bother.

Answer (score 1):

Internal TCP state is generally *not* made available to application programs.

Your options are:

- modify the kernel to allow access to this via `getsockopt()`
- use a user-space TCP library that is implemented on top of raw IP datagrams (perhaps [ioremap](http://www.ioremap.net/projects/unetstack/) though I've never used it)
- find some way to do what you want *without* this information

Personally, I recommend the last.